# How to change the css color code permanent using php

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to make theme in user part, so i can select the color for the website. what i need is - when i selected the color it should change the color code in style.css and save. 
Files : index.php and style.css or php

Css code i used :

```
:root{
     --maincolor: #fe7c60; //**trying to change this code** 
}

h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover,
h4 a:hover, h5 a:hover, h6 a:hover {
    color: var(--maincolor);
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    color: var(--maincolor);
}
body .bg-color-reset a {
    color: var(--maincolor);
}
.btn {
    background-color: var(--maincolor);
    border: 1px solid var(--maincolor);
}

.dropcap {
    color: var(--maincolor);
}

blockquote {
    border-left: 3px solid var(--maincolor);
}
    blockquote .author {
        color: var(--maincolor);
    }

.fc-iconbox.fc-style-4.fc-hover .fc-iconbox-content {
    background-color: var(--maincolor);
}

.fc-tab .fc-tab-heading {
    background: var(--maincolor);
}

.fc-accordion {
    background: var(--maincolor);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can edit the css file directly with php function [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fwrite.php). Is that what you are looking for ?

```
$handle = fopen("file.css", "r+");
fseek($handle, $the-place-you-want-to-write);
fwrite($handle, $the-color-you-got-from-the-user);
```

Comment: ```$handle = fopen("file.css", "r+");
fseek($handle, $the-place-you-want-to-write);
fwrite($handle, $the-color-you-got-from-the-user);
```
or sth like that

Comment: But a better way to do would be to create the css sheet with php. For example : 
`--maincolor:<?php echo $_POST['color'] ;?>;`

Comment: Thanks @Hugo Trentesaux